# Wifi Won't Connect, Tried Everything - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS TP-Link WN722N

Tags: networking, ath9k, tp-link

I have an ubuntu 16.04 with a TP-Link WN722N AR9271 chipset.
It was all working perfectly for months, and then it started to drop out occasionally. Once I started to try and fix the problem and a few upgrades later... it just got gradually worse until today I can almost never use the internet on my ubuntu machine.

I have installed the firmware-atheros, I have installed many versions of the ath9k_htc drivers. I have added the wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no line to my NetworkManager.conf file.

I am considering backing up my system and upgrading to 17 or 18 - would this renew all of the network drivers?

Is there a way of restoring all the drivers and network settings to default without upgrading?

If you need any more info to diagnose the problem just ask, any help will be appreciated.

Here are all the relevant details and info:

sudo lshw -class network:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: 70:4d:7b:8a:37:e7
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:127 memory:df100000-df11ffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@3:1
   logical name: wlx18d6c70bcdad
   serial: 18:d6:c7:0b:cd:ad
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.15.0-24-generic firmware=1.4 ip=192.168.1.33 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Sudo iwlist scanning

```
wlx18d6c70bcdad  Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: C4:ED:34:D6:3F:0D
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Manuel Araya"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000008145be5a56
                Extra: Last beacon: 24ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000C4D616E75656C204172617961
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A7E191BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606051700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD760050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001073C3D75D61A700EB200FCBB3A024432A1021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D4150100800020084103C000101
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180207F02C0000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
      Cell 02 - Address: 1C:B0:44:C6:78:87
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Wifi Puc\xC3\xB3n Chile"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000005e0f957de6
                Extra: Last beacon: 1488ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00115769666920507563C3B36E204368696C65
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 050402030000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 0B0500002F0000
                IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606081100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000000040
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180200000C0000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 46057200010000
```

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

My card:

```
Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
```

TL - WN722N

/etc/network/interfaces File:
I have since commented out the lines at the bottom as they did not resolve the issue.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# the loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# the primary network interface
# auto wlx18d6c70bcdad
# iface wlx18d6c70bcdad inet dhcp
```

sudo lsusb output:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
```

sudo lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  0
arc4                   16384  2
ath9k_htc              77824  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              475136  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              622592  4 ath9k_htc,mac80211,ath,ath9k_common
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    98304  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm                   598016  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd                    81920  20 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_pad              180224  0
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
i915                 1630208  59
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
ahci                   36864  3
mxm_wmi                16384  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
e1000e                249856  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               147456  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
drm                   401408  7 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    24576  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
video                  45056  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
match-device=wlx18d6c70bcdad
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Ubuntu connection settings:
[Ubuntu connection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eOw9.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you use a LiveUSB with 18.04 on it?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have 18.04 on a stick to test it.